# python-django: adding math in my views.py?

Tags: python, django, math

Do I need to import some kind of module to do math in my views.py?

```
def calc(request):
    if 'pv' in request.GET and 'r' in request.GET:
        pv = request.GET['pv']
        r = request.GET['r']

        calcPV = pv * r
        return render(request, 'main/index.html',
            {
                'pv': pv,
                'r': r,
                'calcPV': calcPV,
            })
    return render(request, 'main/index.html')
```

For example purposes, I'm trying to do a simple multiplication: `calcPV = pv * r` but its not working. Am I doing this wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to import any module to do a multiplication.

You might have to cast your parameters first. For example:

`pv = int(request.GET['pv'])`

In the HTML, you can show the results like this:

```
{{ calcPV }}
```

Comment: I was hoping that might just be it, but still getting an error: `A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.` in web browser, and in my terminal: `OperationalError: no such table: django_session`

Comment: I hope you did the same for r as well

Comment: Oh I see what I did wrong, r could be a decimal, so instead, needed to do `float()` instead of `int()`. thanks!